# how many elements on list with scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

i need to write a function which calculates how many elements on list with scheme language.

for example

`(howMany 'a)` returns 0
`(howMany '(a b))` returns 1
`(howMany '(a (b c)))` returns 2

how can i do that? i did not want a working code, just only an idea for do that. so maybe you should consider to remove working codes. :) thank you

Comment: Is (a ((b) c) d) valid, and if so, should howMany return 3 when called on it?

Comment: yes, it is valid and returns 3.

Comment: My previous test case was too ambiguous; do you want length of the input, or the deepest nesting level?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean but it's most probably deepest nesting level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fold answers will work. However, if this is homework, you may be trying to do this using only simple built-in functions. There are two possible answers.

Here's the naive way:

```
(define (howMany list)
  (if (null? list)
      0
      (+ 1 (howMany (cdr list)))
  )
)
```

(Your implementation of Scheme may have a function `empty?` instead of `null?`.)

However, this algorithm will take an amount of space linearly proportional to the number of elements in the list, because it will store `(+ 1 ...)` for each element of the list before doing any of the additions. Intuitively, you shouldn't need this. Here's a better algorithm that avoids that issue:

```
(define (howMany list)
   (define (iter numSoFar restOfList)
      (if (null? restOfList)  
          numSoFar
          (iter (+ numSoFar 1) (cdr restOfList))
      )
   )
   (iter 0 list)
)
```

(Bonus points: use Scheme's `(let iter ...)` syntax to write this more succinctly. I used this style because it's more clear if you only know a few Scheme primitives.)

Comment: Usually, giving out working code in homework is not a good way of teaching someone. The teacher wanted the student to solve it, not a random person in SO. I understand you wanted to help, though.

Comment: @LiraNuna: Good point. Thanks - I'll try to do better next time.

Comment: also fails the second test case

Answer (score 2):

This will most likely get down-voted for this phrase, but, I don't know scheme. I am, however, familiar with functional programming.

If there is no built-in for this, start by 'folding' the list with start value of 0 and add 1 on every additional fold.

Comment: There is `foldr` and `foldl` funcions in scheme, +1

Comment: The direction should not matter.

Comment: @Nathan Sanders: in R6RS, specifically

Answer (score 1):

It is simply counting the number of elements in the list.

```
(define howMany
   (lambda (list)
      (cond
         [(not (list? list)) 0]
         [(null? list) 0]
         [else (+ 1 (howMany (cdr list)))])))
```

Comment: You could combine the first two `cond` lines here by just testing `(not (pair? list))`.